# How to associate a customized number with exception

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, database-programming

I have some code where I want to throw two exceptions; however, the exception are basically the same but with different values. I would like to know an elegant generic way to determine which of these errors occurred.

I know I can do two try catches or that I can set a Boolean to determine the success of query. I am also aware that this can be done in 1 query; however, I need to be able to determine if the company key was wrong or if PA id was wrong. I also know that I can create my own exception and add an additional field to it. Unfortunately, I do not believe that any of these are the optimal solution and this has been bothering me for quite some time.

Any information as to best practice would be appreciated.

```
using (var ora = new OracleConnection(Data.ConnectionString))
{
    String sqlGetCompanyId = "SELECT COMPANY_ID FROM companies WHERE key = :key";
    String sqlValidateDelete = "select * from pa where PA_ID = :paid AND COMPANY_ID = :cid";

    ora.Open();
    int CompanyId = 0;

    using (var Command = ora.CreateCommand())
    {
        Command.CommandText = sqlGetCompanyId;
        Command.Parameters.Add(":key", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = cKey;

        using (var reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
        {
            if (reader.Read())
               CompanyId = unchecked((int)((long)reader["COMPANY_ID"]));
            else
               throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Company Key");
        }
     }

     using (var Command = ora.CreateCommand())
     {
         Command.CommandText = sqlValidateDelete;
         Command.Parameters.Add(":cid", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = CompanyId;
         Command.Parameters.Add(":paid", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = PAID;

         using (var reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
         {
             if (!reader.Read())
                throw new ArgumentException("Price Agreement Id for this company does not exist");
             rv = unchecked((int)((long)reader["ROW_VERSION"]));
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Why are you using a reader to determine if a row exists?  Count(*) is more direct.  And why use exceptions?  Just return a byte return code.

Comment: @Blam The reason I've done this is because I actually require information from the reader in addition to knowing if it exist. i.e CompanyId = unchecked((int)((long)reader["COMPANY_ID"]));

Comment: OK then use reader.HasRows or IsDBNull rather than unchecked.  And still why exception rather than a return status?

Comment: The reason is because oracle reader starts before the first row and returns "true if there are more rows; otherwise, false." as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.read.aspx)

Furthermore, even if I did reader.hasRows, I'd need to do that in addition to reader.read() because I actually use the data immediately after I check for it its existence.

Lastly, this is only part of a method. I did not design the way the system is suppose to work nor am I at liberty to change it. This also has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: I know how rdr works.  Checking for HasRows is faster than making it throw an exception and you don't need unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a custom exception for each:

```
public class InvalidCompanyKeyException : ArgumentException {
   public InvalidCompanyKeyException() : base() {}
   public InvalidCompanyKeyException(string message) : base(message) {}
   public InvalidCompanyKeyException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) {}
}

public class PriceAgreementIdNotFoundException : ArgumentException {
   public PriceAgreementIdNotFoundException() : base() {}
   public PriceAgreementIdNotFoundException(string message) : base(message) {}
   public PriceAgreementIdNotFoundException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) {}
}
```

You can catch these separately, or you can catch either one as `ArgumentException`. I've included three separate constructors for each exception because [that's what Microsoft recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). They also recommend making the exception serializable if they'll be used in certain scenarios, but your example doesn't seem to require serialization.

Comment: Its a good thing you included that information as this is actually used in a web service which means its a very good idea for it to be serializable.

Comment: Just lucky then :) You need an additional constructor when the exception is serializable. The link in my answer covers this but doesn't show an actual example; I'm sure one could be Googled up.

Answer (score 1):

How about defining your own exception

```
public class MyException : ArgumentException
{
    public MyException(string s) : base(s)
    {
    }
    public int MyValue { set; get; }
}
```

and use it like `throw new MyException("Some Message") { MyValue = 666 };`

Answer (score 1):

You could just [specify the `ParamName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxykka64.aspx) when you create the `ArgumentException`:

```
throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Company Key", "cKey");
...
throw new ArgumentException("Price Agreement Id for this company does not exist",
                            "PAID");
```

And then read it when you catch it:

```
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    if (ex.ParamName == "cKey")
        // something
    else if (ex.ParamName == "PAID")
        // something else
    else
        throw; // something else went wrong, rethrow the error
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great response. I can't believe I didn't think of it.